# Create a secure admin-only section for a php website

Tags: php, https

I have created a website and I want to create a control panel for it. Apart from the obvious login for the admin, could you please name a few common practices to make this part of the website more secure? I mean the techniques that are used different in these kind of pages from those in the normal (user) pages.

Comment: That's rather a rather vague question so it is not really a suitable question for SO. Start at https://www.owasp.org/.

Comment: I suggest you use Google and search for PHP user authentication scripts. Look at as many as you can, because even though most scripts are alike, every script has/uses something the other script doesn't. StackOverflow is for help with specific problems/issues/questions, not for help with building websites/scripts. Good luck ;)

Comment: Why don't you [google some php security measures](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+security+measures) - attempt to implement them and if you have a problem with a specific method come and post it here.  You are already implying one such method (not php) but using a secure connection (SSL) - that's some server configuration though and has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Use an established framework with a tested authentication system - that's less likely to have security issues than custom code. Symfony, Zend, CodeIgnitor, CakePHP, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to focus on keeping your credentials safe:

- Use htmlspecialchars() on anything sent to your server to prevent XSS.
- Use cryptogrpahic functions like SHA1() + Salt for your user
  passwords.
- Use Anti-CSRF Token's.
- Use Paramaterized Queries or Prepared Statements for database calls.
- HTTPS never hurts.

Comment: Also, configurable IP range filtering.

Comment: The php.net website says to avoid sha1() and to use crypt() or hash() instead, in conjunction with a salt. http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: crypt() uses either DES or MD5, both which are inferior algorithms to SHA1().